# I want AWS Lambda Event Notify for all regions

Tags: amazon-web-services

To set up AWS Event Notification using Lambda Services I'm facing this error except the us-east region.

**Error:-The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint.**
*Also, Every time when I'm creating any function in AWS Lambda by default region is set to the us-east.*

Permission/Policy for IAM Role I'm using is:-
AmazonSESFullAccess

1. AWSLambdaExecute
2. AWSLambdaRole

Please help me out with this

Comment: Are you trying to cause an object uploaded to a bucket in region X to trigger a Lambda function in region Y? Or have you simply misconfigured this? If the former, you could potentially have the Lambda in region X itself synchronously invoke a Lambda in region Y. Not ideal, but perhaps workable.

Comment: @Rahul Please tell us exactly what you were doing when the error occurred, and what you were wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you @John and for your response.

I just want a notification on my email if anything is deleted or put on any S3 bucket through the Lambda function.
As the ARN number is autogenerated to us-east regions I'm unable to implement the Lambda function to other regions bucket events. 

This is the error coming is I'm setting up the event to other regions :point-down:
Error:-The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod and for your response.

I just want a notification on my email if anything is deleted or put on any S3 bucket through the Lambda function.
As the ARN number is autogenerated to us-east regions I'm unable to implement the Lambda function to other regions bucket events. 

This is the error coming is I'm setting up the event to other regions :point-down:
Error:-The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda function for S3 Event Notification **must be in same region** as the bucket. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/setup-event-notification-destination.html):

> The Lambda function **must be in the same region** as your S3 bucket.

If you want to use same S3 notification, you have to **re-broadcast** the event to other regions. This can be achieved, for example, by having your original lambda function publish messages to **SNS topics** from different regions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Marcin for your response.

I just want a notification on my email if anything is deleted or put on any S3 bucket through the Lambda function.
As the ARN number is autogenerated to us-east regions I'm unable to implement the Lambda function to other regions bucket events. 

This is the error coming is I'm setting up the event to other regions :point-down:
Error:-The notification destination service region is not valid for the bucket location constraint.

Comment: @RahulKumar Hi. No problem. Notification Target (lambda in your case) must be in same region as the bucket. If you have buckets in different regions, in each region you need corresponding lambda function.

Comment: I m creating new lambda for different regions but ARN autogenerated to us-east.

Is there any other policy I have assign except this 2 policy:
1. AWSLambdaExecute
2. AWSLambdaRole

Comment: @RahulKumar If ARN is for us-east-1 this means your functions are in this region. Do you switch in console to different regions before you create the functions?

Comment: thank you for helping me. Can you tell me how to switch in console for different regions because I don't know and not able to find it out on internet.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps or process how to switch in console for different regions because I don't know and not able to find it out on internet.

Comment: @RahulKumar There is menu in the top-right in the console. Please check screenshot from my answer.